# If $u\in D^{s, p}(\mathbb R^n)$, is that true that $u\in C(\mathbb R^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $0<s<1$, $p>1$ and $n>sp$. For $u\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n))$ let
$$ [u]_{s, p} =\left(\iint_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}\right)^{\frac1p}$$
be the ussual Gagliardo seminorm of $u$.
Let us define
$$D^{s, p}(\mathbb R^n)=\{ f\in L^{p^*_s}(\mathbb R^n) : [u]_{s, p}<+\infty\},$$
where $p^*_s$ is the fractional critical exponent $p^*_s=np/(n-sp)$.

For $p\in (1, \infty)$, the space $D^{s, p}(\mathbb R^n)$ is a separable and reflexive Banach spaces with respect to the Gagliardo seminorm. Moreover, it can also be understood as the respective completions of the space $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with respect to $[\cdot]_{s, p}$.

The question is: if $u\in D^{s, p}(\mathbb R^n)$, hence one can say that $u\in C(\mathbb R^n)$. There exists any embedding theorem or something like that?

Comment: The space you described is also the called homogeneous Sobolev-Soblodeckij space also denoted $\dot{\mathrm{W}}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is also the homogeneous Besov space $\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{s}_{p,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: There is only one homogeneous Besov space that is made of continuous functions, that is $\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{n/p}_{p,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So none of your spaces above are made of continuous functions.

Comment: The strategy to disprove your claim, is the following. Argue by contradiction that $D^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{s}_{p,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is contained in $\mathrm{C}^0_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The closed graph theorem implies that the inclusion must be continuous. Hence, on has for all $u\in D^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$\lVert u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^\infty} \leqslant C [u]_{s,p}.$$

However, a dilation argument shows that $u$ must be identically zero, which is the contradiction we desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $sp>n$, if the Gagliardo seminorm is finite, you can prove that $u$ has a Holder continuous representative. But in the range $sp<n$ you can have discontinuous functions as ToGle wrote in the comments. Take $n=1$ and $u=\chi_{[0,1]}$. You should get two double integrals. One is
$$2\int^1_0\int^\infty_1\frac1{(x-y)^{1+sp}}dxdy=\frac2{sp}\int^1_0\frac{1}{(1-y)^{sp}}dy<\infty$$ and the other
is
$$2\int^1_0\int_{-\infty}^0\frac1{(y-x)^{1+sp}}dxdy=\frac2{sp}\int^1_0\frac{1}{y^{sp}}dy<\infty$$
When $n>1$ take the characteristic function of a cube although the calculation is more complicated.

Comment: Gio67, thank you for the answer. Could you please provide a reference for the case $n<sp$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I allow myself to comment that the existence of Hölder representative is not that clear in the case of homogeneous function spaces with $s>n/p$ as well as their definition. You will have the existence of Hölder continuous representative but only up to a constant that you cannot choose canonically.

Comment: Proposition 2.20 from the book "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations" by Bahouri Chemin and Danchin, for the adapted Sobolev embeddings, $\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{s}_{\infty,\infty}$ being the Besov space for which the norm coincides with the (homogeneous) Hölder norm.

Comment: Theorem 2.36 of the same book to see that all the the function spaces, and mostly their norms, I told you about are actually the norms and spaces you where expecting.

Comment: @ToGle, thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on how you define the homogeneous spaces. For me, they are functions $u$ in $L^p_{\text{loc}}$ such that the Gagliardo seminorm is finite.  Using this definition, you can find the proof in Theorem 7.23 in https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/229 If you use a different definition, then I don't know.

Comment: My comments were probably unclear, sorry. It was more about the issues arising from the usual constructions when $s\geqslant n/p$, here built over $\mathrm{L}^p_{\text{loc}}$ (but tempered distributions modulo constants yields the same): for $u\in\mathrm{L}^p_{\text{loc}}$ we cannot distinguish $$u+c\text{, and }u+c'$$ for $c,c'\in\mathbb{C}$ with those homogeneous (semi-)norms.  Both are elements of $\mathrm{L}^p_{\text{loc}}$, so how could we distinguish two representatives through this single embedding with homogeneous (semi-)norms ? A similar issue would happen for traces.

Comment: Well, as I said, it depends on how you want to define the homogeneous spaces. If you want them to be Banach spaces, then you have to mod out constants, and so your objections are valid. I prefer not to do that, because then it gets confusing when you talk about inclusions and the relation with the non homogeneous spaces. Elements of these two spaces would be incompatible. If you are ok losing the Banach structure, then you don't need to mod out the constants.

Comment: If you don't mod out constants then you only have a locally convex space. If you want to make it Hausdorff, you could add the $L^p$ norm on a ball.

Comment: Any chance to have $C^{1, \alpha}$ regularity if $sp>n$?

Comment: No. A Lipschitz continuous function would be an example